# Invalid Configuration Matrix Block

Tags: entries

When I tried to use the old page, I got this error on the backend page.

Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
Invalid Matrix block type ID: 147

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: We'll need a bit more info in order to be able to help I'm afraid. Are you getting that error on the front-end of the site? In the control panel? Are you doing anything to trigger it? Can you share a full stack trace? What version of Craft is this on?